# JQuery Hover Method - Out function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, jquery-hover

I am applying an hover effect on an image with JQuery.

State on page load :

[image: On Page Load]

State on hover :

[image: State on Hover]

State on mouseout :

[image: State on Hover]

Here is the code snippet :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".image-container").hover(function() {
    $(this).parents().children().children('.image-01').css({'background-color':'#D4E619', 'opacity': '0.5'}),
   
 (function() {
    $(this).parents().children().children('.image-01').css({'background-color':'#FFFFF','height':'0', 'opacity': '0', 'visibility' :'hidden'});
    });
});
});
```

I tried several css instructions but the image keeps the hover state.

Edit :

The final goal is to have a different hover color on several images  inside a grid. All elements of the grid have the same classname.

I use a first JQuery function to append the classnames and then, generates a specific hover state on some images.

Comment: what's the point of that anon function you don't call

Comment: Why not just use CSS? Why add JavaScript into it? `.image-container:hover .image-01 { background-color: #D4E619; opacity: 0.5; }`

Comment: @epascarello  The hidden goal is to have a different hover color on several images  inside a grid. All elements of the grid have the same classname. I use a first JQuery function to append the classnames and then, generates a specific hover state.

Comment: So why are the classnames set with color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you mixed in and out functions into single one. So your second function that (I assume) should be called on mouse out is never called.

You should unwrap that function from first one and put as second argument for `.hover`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".image-container").hover(
    function() {
      $(this).parents().children().children('.image-01').css({
        'background-color': '#D4E619',
        'opacity': '0.5'
      })
    },
    function() {
      $(this).parents().children().children('.image-01').css({
        'background-color': '#FFFFF',
        'height': '0',
        'opacity': '0',
        'visibility': 'hidden'
      });
    }
  );
});
```

---

Some suggestions (quite abstract since no HTML is provided):

1. You can reduce complexity of selector by finding closest unique wrapper and then find desired element: `$(this).closes('.image-wrapper').find('.image-01')`
2. Via JS apply only display/opacity. Via CSS set rules for element when it's shown, no point in setting it's background if it's not visible: `$(this).[..].show(), $(this).[..].hide()`
3. I assume you can just do it with css: `.image-wrapper:hover .image-01{display: block;}`

Comment: Works better this way... I will try to modifiy the code with your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

1. Use id for the image, so you can reduce dom complexity.
2. Use two separate events (.hover and .mouseout)
3. Use arrow functions rather than 'function' keyword

Example:

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
    $("#image-01").hover(()=>{
        /* css code for hover here */
    }
    $("#image-01").mouseout(()=>{
        /* css code for mouseout here */
    }
}
```

Edit:

1. Maybe you can warp all of your images in a div element. 
   Then you can use

   let images = $(' /* container id */ ').children()

   To get its children.

   Then just loop through the images and add hover events

Comment: If there is multiple elements, then it's unwise to use ID's. Also why use two events if there is literally mouseout event callback incorporated in hover event? `Then just loop through the images and add hover events` - that's why you use classes and jQuery does the job for you without explicit loops